# Finding duplicates in Dataframe and returning 1s and 0s

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
data_list = [['Name', 'Fruit'],
              ['Abel', 'Apple'],
              ['Abel', 'Pear'],
              ['Abel', 'Coconut'],
              ['Abel', 'Pear'],
              ['Benny', 'Apple'],
              ['Benny', 'Apple'],
              ['Cain', 'Apple'],
              ['Cain', 'Coconut'],
              ['Cain', 'Pear'],
              ['Cain', 'Lemon'],
              ['Cain', 'Orange']]

record_df = pd.DataFrame(data_list[1:], columns = data_list[0])
```

I am trying to create another DataFrame to tell me if someone has the same fruit.

Expected Output:

```
Name | Repeated_Fruits
Abel | 1
Benny| 1
Cain | 0
```

I have tried

```
bool_series = record_df.duplicated(subset=['Name'], keep=False)
record_df_2 = record_df[~bool_series]
```

But everything is True. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `pd.crosstab`

```
out = pd.crosstab(df.Name, df.Fruit).gt(1).sum(axis=1).reset_index(name='rep_name')
Out[10]: 
    Name  rep_name
0   Abel         1
1  Benny         1
2   Cain         0
```

Answer (score 1):

The `subset` parameter is for saying where you're looking for duplicates, so it should be `'Fruit'`. The `name` column is what you want to group by, so you can do:

```
record_df.groupby('Name').apply(lambda x: x.duplicated().sum())

Name
Abel     1
Benny    1
Cain     0
dtype: int64
```

You say that you want 0 and 1 as output, but this will give larger numbers if there are more than one duplicate.